# 之后 vs 过后 usage & differences

Tags: meaning, usage, difference, word

Based on the dictionary, 之后 = after, afterwards while 过后 = afterwards, after. I wanted to find the difference in usage between those two words, so I analysed some sample sentences. I feel like 过后 is mostly used for describing "after the event" while 之后 seems to fit for anything. Is 过后 and 之后 used as I described or are there other ways to differentiate their usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "(noun) 之后" = "after (noun)"

Example:

"2018 之后" = "after 2018"

"暴風之后" = "after the storm"

> "(noun) 过后" = "after (noun) had passed"

Example:

"2018 过后" = "after 2018 had passed"

"暴風过后" = "after the storm had passed"

> "之后 (verb)" / "过后 (verb)" = "afterward (verb)"

Example:

"之后再補償" = "compensate afterward"

"过后再補償" = "compensate afterward"

> "(verb) 之后" = "after (verb)"

Example:

"清朝灭亡之后" =  "After Qing Dynasty ended"

"政府成立之后" = "After the the government is founded"

> we cannot use "verb + 过后".  Both "清朝灭亡过后" and  "政府成立过后" are grammatically incorrect

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bkrs：**过后** (1) [afterwards]∶往后
这个问题先这么解决, 有什么事, 过后再说
(2) [later]∶后来
那件事我过后才知道 after the event syn. 后来, 后头, 嗣后, 随后, 
过后 may **not** occur as **one word** in phrases like (taken from bkrs) 仔细想过后再动作。紧急情况过后的评价.连雨天过后出现了晴天.where 过  functions as experienced action marker,1) completion of an action
2) that an action has taken place, but does not continue up to the present, and 后 as postposition  corresponding to English preposition,

on the other hand 之后 occurs as one word both as adverb: afterwards, later 之后他到国外去了 and postposition: after,从那之后 since then
两周之后  她毕业之后  天黑之后 syn. 后, 往后, 尔后, 以后